# Can't adjust brightness

Tags: drivers, laptop, brightness

I have a Toshiba Satellite A105-4244 (Intel Chipset+Integrated Graphics) and I can't adjust the brightness. Neither the buttons nor the system settings/brightness and lock work.

Also I tried the grub suggestions `acpi_backlight` and it didn't solve anything.

EDIT: Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: which version of OS?

Answer (score 0):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
xgamma -gamma 0.5
```

Or

```
xgamma -gamma 0.6
```

similarly

```
xgamma -gamma 0.4
```

Comment: Thanks but it won't do. This changes gamma not monitor brightness.